# Disable divs with checkboxes using class approach

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have combination of divs and check-boxes. In each div there are text-boxes and radio buttons. So at the top level if I want to disable any div I should be able to do so with checkbox corresponding to that div.

I have written JQuery to do so but if I check or uncheck checkbox for one div, it is also affecting another div and its content. So I want a class based approach to get this functionality. Also on page load, the div contents should be disabled. Thanks

```
$(".disableDivCheckbox").click(function () {
        $(".disableDiv *").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if checkbox is checked remove class from div on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621150/if-checkbox-is-checked-remove-class-from-div-on-click)

Comment: show us your html structure

Answer (score 1):

Refr this code working fine.

```
 <script>
  $(function () {
      $("#chkPassport").click(function () {
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#dvPassport").show();
          } else {
            $("#dvPassport").hide();
          }
       });
   });

</script>

 //html/php code


    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                <label class="form-group col-sm-3">
<input  type="checkbox" id="chkPassport" name="chkPassport" value="first_checkbox">Add Payment</label>

                <div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">

                    <label class="form-group col-sm-12">Payment Type</label>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                <?php
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare('Select pay_type_name from tbl_payment_type');
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
                    print '<select class="col-sm-11" name="pay_type_name" id="pay_type_name">';
                    foreach ($result as $row) {
                    print "<option value=".$row['pay_type_name'].">".$row['pay_type_name']."</option>";
                    }
                    print '</select>';              
                ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```